# Schedule YARN application on active/standby nodes

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I would like to have a cluster that is split to 2 sub-clusters: "active" nodes and "standby" nodes. 
Normally, when an application is scheduled I would like it to run on the "active" nodes. But if no "active" node is healthy, I would like it to run on the "standby" nodes.

Is there a way to achieve such behavior in YARN?

To give a bit more details, the "active" nodes of the cluster will be located in different zone than the the "standby" nodes (but not so far from them). 
Thus we try to achieve multi-zone high availability for our application. Meaning, upon disaster in the "active" zone, the application will be recovered and scheduled on the "standby" zone.

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you running?

Comment: Currently we are just checking our options. We are open for any version that gives us that functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To route jobs to specific nodes, you will need Node Labels.  Capacity Scheduler has had them for a while (2.6 or earlier), but for Fair Scheduler I think they were planning on supporting them in Hadoop 3.x.

Another option to consider is YARN federation where you have more than one YARN cluster so your 2nd would be in zone 2 and you can re-route your job to zone 2 if zone 1 has issues.

#### References

- [YARN Node Labels](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html)
- [Hadoop: YARN Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/Federation.html)

Comment: Thanks @tk421. Using Node Labels, can I configure something like "prefer selecting nodes with 'active' labels, and if not healthy select others"? As far as I understood - I can't (though, in k8s it is possible).

Comment: You'd have to do this via scheduling queues.  Node health is part of YARN automatically meaning if your Node Manager is unusable, it will mark itself as unavailable.  See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManager.html#Health_Checker_Service.